# PhpStorm make grouping like Xcode

Tags: xcode, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Can I make a grouping my php pages like Xcode group in PhpStorm ? Is there any suggestion ?

> There are two types of folders in Xcode: groups and folder references.
>   You can use groups to organize files in your project without affecting
>   their structure on the actual file system. This is great for code,
>   because you’re only going to be working with your code in Xcode.

[referance](http://struct.ca/2010/xcode-folder-references/)

Comment: How does it look in Xcode?

Comment: I edited my question. It looks like folder but groups organize files without affecting their structure on the actual file system.

Comment: I dont believe that *feature* exists in either PhlStorm or AppCode ... thank god. I dont know how many times i had to rebuild the group structure from scratch with Xcode because it self-destroyed the logical hierarchy of groups. I actually switched to AppCode out of sheer frustration about this (not to mention the numerous other IntelliJ features). Working with a flat directory can become a real pain with projects that have 10K+ files.

Comment: Nothing like that in PhpStorm. The best remotely-similar alternative I can think of is to create custom Scope that would include only files/folders you want to see (but it still will follow your folder structure) and switch to such view when needed instead of default "Project" in Project View panel.